# значение слова "аксессуар"

Tags: семантика

Приемлемо ли употреблять прилагательное "дополнительный" с существительным "аксессуар"? Насколько мне известно, значение слова "аксессуар" и подразумевает что-либо дополнительное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Трудно гадать, не имея контекста. Фразу целиком приведите, пожалуйста.

В целом Вы, конечно, правы, если просто написать что-то типа "товар с дополнительными аксессуарами", то это плеоназм или тавтология. К сожалению, с легкой руки маркетологов давно стало привычным, но от того не менее неправильным.

Но если, например, есть какое деление аксессуаров на основные дополнительные (почему нет?) или в "аксессуар" укладывается несколько другой смысл (не "дополнительный", а "принадлежность" - тоже фиксируется словарем), то почему бы и нет?!

Тут еще такая штука. Несмотря на привычность "аксессуар" пока даже не всеми словарями фиксируется. Так что по поводу значения и сочетаемости тоже не все до конца установлено.

Comment: дополнительный аксессуар для кресла - чехол для сиденья

Comment: Да, это выглядит излишеством. Если уж чехол - дополнительный, то что тогда основной? Я бы исправил по возможности.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще говоря, Сочетание "дополнительный аксессуар" вполне корректно, поэтому следует судить о правильности его применения в конкретных случаях.

АКСЕССУАРЫ, [от франц. accessoire - дополнительный, вспомогательный]. 2. Принадлежность чего-л.; **сопутствующие предметы**. Одежда и а.

Чехол - сопутствующий предмет, то есть аксессуар для автомобиля. Чехлы могут входить в базовую комплектацию,  а могут предлагаться в качестве **дополнительного аксессуара**, например: летний чехол - дополнительный чехол к автомобильному креслу, который легко снимается и стирается.

Еще пример: Чехол на сиденья с рисунком — это не только практичная вещь, но и **дополнительный стильный аксессуар** для автомобиля.